# Set a default value and reload to current value

Tags: javascript

Please I need help on this. I'm still struggling with JavaScript.
I wrote a function for price change and percentage change which is working fine. The price and percentage change is been fetched by an api.

I want to be able reload the price and percentage change without reloading the entire page and on reload, I want a default value to be displayed until it's current value is updated.

Comment: This is one reason why people use javascript frameworks like React. Static webpages have to reload whenever something changes, whereas React will only reload the specific part of the DOM (virtual DOM) that changed. Look into using `npx create-react-app ./`, you'll need to install node and npm first... it's not necessary but I would strongly advise installing nvm (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) before node and npm, it'll make things a lot easier later on.

Comment: Show your code and please be more specific of what you want to do.
I understand you want to modify the DOM, an specific piece, but I would need to see your code and be sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: @srWebDev i think it's a bit too drastic to suggest a framework change in order to serve such a trivial task that can be achieved using VanillaJS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would display a placeholder until your fetch is complete. I used setTimeout to simulate your fetch call. I'm not sure if your question was also about how to do the fetch, but here is the MDN article on it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```js
div = document.getElementById("some-id");
window.setTimeout(function() {
  div.innerHTML = "New Value";
}, 3000);
div.innerHTML = "Temp Value";
```

```html
<div id="some-id"></div>
```